# Can you write a comment if a question is closed?`

Tags: support, comment, closed-questions

If a question is closed, can you still write comments? Or will that not be allowed?

I'm just asking because one of my questions was closed, but there was somebody who answered it while it was still open. So if I write a comment to that answer, will that person be able to see my comment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can still write comments to a closed question.

If a question (or an answer) is locked, then you cannot write comments.